# Is load testing a server using web services same as load testing scenario based?

Tags: performance-testing

I am new to performance testing and also to jmeter...I newly joined an organisation that develops mobile apps and web server.Here the currently way of load testing is that dev team provides the web services along with the body and the expected the response. Currently the team is using http requests in jmeter for each webservice provided and running it for concurrent users. My assumption was to record the critical scenarios in the application and then run for multiple users.
So i would like to understand whether the load on the server is same when load testing is performed using webservices as compared to scenario based load testing. If its not, then can someone help me to understand how it is different and what it could be impact on performance testing.The team is currently saying that even if it is record it is still a url as mentioned in webservice
Appreciate any help...

Thanks,
Visu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on the scenario you want to test.

1. If you are load testing a mobile app, it is better to test the web-services which will have the actual load (since every user will have a separate app on their mobile phones/Tablets).
2. If you are load testing a web application, it is good to test both UI based scenarios and the web-services.

Hope this will help.